# Pandas - Convert hh:mm and hh:mm:ss to standard hh:mm:ss in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas column "hour" and it has hourly time, but some are listed as (hour:minute) `1:00` some as `24:00:00`. I would like to convert all of them to as, `1:00:00` (i.e. hour:minute:seconds). I tried converting to `to_datetime`,but no luck. Thanks for your help.

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], format='%H:%M%:%S', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: could you create a example with your problem, something like your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` to add trailing ":00" to those strings that don't have it, and then convert to `datetime` or `timedelta` (whichever).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': ['1:00', '23:15:00']})
df

       hour
0      1:00
1  23:15:00

pd.to_timedelta(np.where(df.hour.str.count(':') == 1, df.hour + ':00', df.hour))
# TimedeltaIndex(['01:00:00', '23:15:00'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

---

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_timedelta(
    np.where(df['hour'].str.count(':') == 1, df['hour'] + ':00', df['hour']))
```

Comment: The column should be `df.hour` in order to work with the users question

Comment: No problem. Good answer!

Comment: @coldspeed, Thanks! This works perfect. I also have a `date` column and I used `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`. Together with `hour` and `date`, I can easily sort my data.

Answer (score 4):

you can use strftime() and cast to datetime if you want work with date and time:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'hour': ['21:51','11:07:20', '08:33:16', '09:01']})
df1['Clean_hour'] = (df1.hour.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                             .apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)))

print(df1,df1.dtypes)

       hour Clean_hour
0     21:51   21:51:00
1  11:07:20   11:07:20
2  08:33:16   08:33:16
3     09:01   09:01:00

hour                  object
Clean_hour    datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well, but when I add the value `24:00:00` it gives me a error, `ValueError: hour must be in 0..23`.

Comment: you have to caast in datetime i add the modification

Comment: Still have the same issue.

Comment: you add another question dunno you want to do with this date. i suggest you to open a new question , you could explain what you want to do with the datetime..the datetime64 is the standard type for pandas datetime

Comment: Basically, I have the `date` column and `time` column. The `time` column ranges from `1:00` to `24:00:00`. I am trying to set the two columns correctly to `to_datetime` and sort them in ascending order. But, in the current form you suggested, having `24:00:00` gives me an error as `ValueError: hour must be in 0..23`. Thanks